# How To Show NULL or ZERO From Inner Join These Two Tables On Two Different Databases?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables on 2 different databases :

**db1.table1**

```
+--------------+--------------------------+
| Username     | Message                  |
+--------------+--------------------------+
| jamesbond    | I need some help         |
| jamesbond    | I need some help         |
| jamesbond    | I need some help         |
| jamesbond    | Mission accomplished     |
+--------------+--------------------------+
```

**db2.table2**

```
+--------------------------+--------------+
| Message                  | Status       |
+--------------------------+--------------+
| I need some help         | Ok           |
| I need some help         | Ok           |
| I need some help         | Bad          |
+--------------------------+--------------+
```

when I do 'INNER JOIN' those tables using this SQL syntax :

```
SELECT A.Username, A.Message
SUM(CASE WHEN `status` = 'Ok' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS StatOK,
SUM(CASE WHEN `status` = 'Bad' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS StatBAD
FROM db1.table1 as A
INNER JOIN db2.table2 as B 
ON A.Message = B.Message
WHERE A.Username = 'jamesbond'
GROUP BY A.Username, A.Message
```

I got this result :

```
+--------------+--------------------------+--------+---------+
| Username     | Message                  | StatOK | StatBAD |
+--------------+--------------------------+--------+---------+
| jamesbond    | I need some help         | 2      | 1       |
+--------------+--------------------------+--------+---------+
```

how to get result like this (message without status on DB2 still appear, but the SUM result can be ZERO or NULL) :

```
+--------------+--------------------------+--------+---------+
| Username     | Message                  | StatOK | StatBAD |
+--------------+--------------------------+--------+---------+
| jamesbond    | I need some help         | 2      | 1       |
| jamesbond    | Mission accomplished     | NULL   | NULL    |
+--------------+--------------------------+--------+---------+
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a `Left Outer Join`, It will get the rows from Left tables and if it doesn't match with Right table then You'll get NULL.

```
SELECT A.Username, A.Message
SUM(CASE WHEN `status` = 'Ok' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS StatOK,
SUM(CASE WHEN `status` = 'Bad' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS StatBAD
FROM db1.table1 as A
LEFT OUTER JOIN db2.table2 as B 
ON A.Message = B.Message
WHERE A.Username = 'jamesbond'
GROUP BY A.Username, A.Message
```